# jQuery with bind or without bind

Tags: jquery

I am wondering what's the difference between these 3 lines of code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
```

vs

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
```

vs

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three use `on()` internally in all current versions of jQuery so there really is no practical difference except two of them will require an extra function call to `on()`.